# Dojo 1.7.2 as OSGI bundle

Tags: xpages

For a project we want to use dojo 1.7.2. I downloaded the version and unzipped everything to a directory.
I added the ibm directory from the js\dojo.1.5.1 directory of my 8.5.3 domino server.
And package all the files as a executable jar file.

In Domino 8.5.3 dojo 1.6.1 is loaded as OSGi bundle and is located in the \osgi\shared\eclipse\plugins

Is there a way to use the newest version of Dojo as OSGi bundle, the same way as dojo 1.6.1 is deployed??

Comment: Just to share my experience: You should test your app before using another dojo version! I have made some tests with higher dojo versions, but some problems occured with the XSP-Object and the date picker.

Comment: I took the 1.6.1 bundle, uncompressed it, replaced the contents with Dojo 1.7.4 leaving all IBM etc stuff there. I also changed the version number in /resource/dojo.properties, compressed everything to a JAR and placed it to \plugins folder. I was not able to make it effective this way. Then I just placed Dojo 1.7.4 to \js folder and XPages started to use it from there. But at least ExtLib DataGrid did not load at all (got some JS errors).

Answer (score 2):

Does your plugin define a Dojo version. I'm looking at the explanation for how the Domino 8.5.3 plugin defines the Dojo version on Page 40 of XPages Portable Command Guide, the section entitled "Installing Multiple Dojo Versions and Determining the Version Used".

It uses an inner text file in the plugin "/resource/dojo.properties" and a property line:

DojoVersion.versionStr=1.6.1

If you define a higher version number in your plugin, I believe that should get used by default. Alternatively, you should be able to define a different version number and use the xsp.client.dojo.script.version property in xsp.properties.

Comment: I'd also suggest unbundling the dojo 1.6.1 jar file and using the IBM folder from that in your 1.7.2 OSGi plugin

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried xsp.client.script.dojo.version?